# Magento Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Shoppersettings_Helper_Image' not found in

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I’ve installed an extension, and after installing it started giving me this error:

Fatal error: Class ‘Mage_Shoppersettings_Helper_Image’ not found in /home/default/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

even after disabling the extension the error remain, I tried to see if the was something I changed in the Mage.php, but my file is still the same the the default file.

does anyone know what can be causing the problem?

Comment: did you clear the cache after disabling the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that the extension has the appropriate definition for the helper is it's config.xml. It will normally look something like.

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <your_module>
            <class>Your_Module_Helper</class>
        </your_module>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Where `your_module` is the part used when calling `Mage::helper('your_module');`